# I'm trying to install elementary os but when trying to boot from the live usb which works on my Windows desktop I get this error, please someone help?

Tags: system-installation

[image: error]

As you can see from the picture, I get this error, I've tried changing boot type to either ufi or legacy and get the same error. I have a desktop with Windows 10 on I can boot from the boot USB no problem on that don't get any errors?

Comment: How much RAM does that laptop has? Not sure if it's related or not but that info might help as it fails mounting SquashFS

Answer (score 1):

Even if it works on the desktop, I would check the MD5 checksum from the elementary.io site after downloading the ISO and then re-create the USB (Balena Etcher should do the trick if you're creating from Windows or Linux).

Comment: I'm not coming from windows, I have deepin on my laptop but windows on my desktop. It boots fine from my desktop but not the laptop, the md5 is as it should be and I've used several different methods including deepin boot maker, dd, rufus, unetbootin. All work on desktop none on laptop.

Comment: Does the laptop has a CDROM drive? Also, can you make sure on the laptop BIOS that boot order is 1st) USB,  2nd) HDD, 3rd) CDROM (If it has one, make sure it's last).